# React is not getting uninstalled in windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I am not able to uninstall react app in windows 10. I tried everything which is in `stackoverflow` but it is not getting uninstalled. I am using `npm` . Even I removed nodejs, still it is not working.

I actually need to use latest version so when I installed `nodejs` and `react` again it is still picking old version of reacr and then app is not running. something really weird

[image]

[image]

Comment: Even I removed nodejs, still it is not working. Are you sure ?

Comment: yes 100%. after remving nodejs I installed again and same issue I am getting.

Comment: in version it is showing 17 but when I create react app it is installing very old almost v1...then app is not running.

Comment: Windows or Linux?

Comment: It is windows. .

Comment: @Mahima did you also tried [to remove it from usr/local/bin?](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8097#issue-533788571)?

Comment: @Mahima lets try above as well

Comment: Even if you uninstall nodeJS you still need to remove the npm folder from the `AppData\Roaming` folder. It's unclear why you're installing CRA or React globally. I think you can just use `npx create-react-app [folder]` from the terminal, and CRA will bootstrap React in that folder only.

Comment: You're uninstalling the global version of React but there may still be local versions between the root and where you're running your command (C:\Users).

Comment: use `npx create-react-app`  after uninstalling to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Run npm cache clean --force
2. Uninstall from Programs & Features with the uninstaller.
3. Reboot (or you probably can get away with killing all node-related processes from Task Manager).
4. Look for these folders and remove them (and their contents) if any still exist. Depending on the version you installed, UAC settings, and CPU architecture, these may or may not exist:

   1. C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodejs
   2. C:\Program Files\Nodejs
   3. C:\Users{User}\AppData\Roaming\npm (or %appdata%\npm)
   4. C:\Users{User}\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache (or %appdata%\npm-cache)
   5. C:\Users{User}.npmrc (and possibly check for that without the . prefix too)
   6. C:\Users{User}\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-*
5. Check your %PATH% environment variable to ensure no references to Nodejs or npm exist.
6. If it's still not uninstalled, type where node at the command prompt and you'll see where it resides -- delete that (and probably the parent directory) too.
7. Reboot, for good measure.